# Installing Magento connector on Open ERP 9

Tags: magento, odoo, odoo-9

From last few days i am exploring Odoo and Magento connector. I have successfully configured Odoo 9 on Ubuntu 14 but now i am finding it difficult to add magento connector module (https://github.com/OCA/connector-magento). I was following this documentation http://odoo-magento-connector.com/guides/installation_guide.html for the instalation and configuration but it looks like its bit old and not updated for Odoo9

Also i put Magento connector plugin inside the **addons** folder but no new module is getting display in odoo admin (Inside the aaps/module section) even after updating the module list.

Do i need to update any configuration file to see the Magento connector module in module list ? I can see this in the backend

[image]

Comment: have you checked the permissions of the folder and your addons path?

Comment: Yes i have checked the folder permission. Folder permissions are set to 777

Comment: have you checked your addons-path (where odoo looks modules)?

Comment: Can you please tell me where does this file located ?

Comment: it's a path where you tell odoo to look for addons it can be specified in a configuration file or you can start the restart the server with these parameters `./odoo.py addons-path=path1,path2,pathN` where path is something like `/opt/odoo/addons`...where is the addon currently located on your machine?

Comment: My module is located in /opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons . I followed your instruction and added the path of magento connectors module. But still in backend only 283 modules are getting display. Can you please guide me what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: did you update the module list?

Comment: Never post your sensitive information online like that...next time send a mail...don't post it on stackoverflow, remember we're not the only people reading this..please delete your comment

Comment: Well its a test server thats why i have shared the detail. Did you check the backend ? By the way may i know your email please ?

Comment: Hi Abhijeet kumar sharma, did you get a solution for this? I was wondering because I have the same damn problem! :X